# How to make a zipapp of current directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, zipapp

From what I understand
`python -m zipapp myapp`
creates a .pyz file of the directory named myapp. How do i create a .pyz of the current folder in which my working directory is set.

I tried `python -m zipapp .` which doesnt work.

What would be the exact argument for packaging of the working directory?

Same doubt for the following:
If I do `pip install -r requirements.txt --target <directory>`, how do i mention current working directory in `<directory>`

Answer (score 0):

Thinking  about the same later, I have reached the conclusion that being able to make the zip file of the directory the terminal is set to doesn't make much sense due to which I don't think there's an solution to this question. Hence I believe zipapp can only take place for a given folder in the directory and not the directory the terminal is set in.